# VSTO Load On Demand

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, vsto, office-addins

I have a Word 2016 VSTO that I developed using VS2015 and deployed to a Windows 10 machine using InstallShield. If I set the LoadBehavior to 3 it loads and works fine.

What I need is for it load on demand. I've tried just setting LoadBehavior to 9 but no dice. The web application that is creating the Word document (that ultimately loads the VSTO) was originally written for Word 2010 and is embedding the VSTO path in the Word document with an added GUID (C:\myAddIn.vsto|GUID|vstolocal). Opening the document created by the web application in Word 2016 throws this error when the VSTO tries to load:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotCreateStartupObjectException:
>   Could not create an instance of startup object myAddin.ThisAddIn

Any tutorials I've seen for VS2013/2015 do not reference embedding a GUID in the VSTO path; just set the LoadBehavior to 9.

There is no Publisher listed in File -> Options ->AddIns. The VSTO is listed under Inactive AddIns which I would expect until it is loaded on demand.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should add, though may be apparent, that I only want the AddIn to load for Word documents created by the web application. Opening Word from the Start menu should not load the AddIn.

Comment: And thinking about this some more... If you only want the code to work with certain documents why aren't you using a document-level customization? You can attach the VSTO code to the document after your web app generates it, using  the ServerDocument class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772091.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I think document-level customization is what I may need.

Comment: OK, I'm writing it up as an "Answer" since others could run into a similar problem. Later, then, I'll clean up the Comments...

Comment: Embedding the GUID like that is typical of document-level add-ins. The GUID comes from SolutionID in the *.csproj file. I don't know how it applies to application-level add-ins though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want code to only execute with certain documents, such as you describe (from Comments)

> I only want the AddIn to load for Word documents created by the web
>   application. Opening Word from the Start menu should not load the
>   AddIn.

then it is probably better to use a document-level customization, rather than an add-in.

The code attached to a document-level customization will load with the document, and unload when the document is closed. It's possible to create a document-level customization and distribute the document, or to attach the code at a later time using VSTO's [ServerDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772091.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class.

Since in your case the documents are being generated by a web app, using ServerDocument is indicated.

Here's the main content of the MSDN article:

=============================================

To attach managed code extensions to a document

1. In a project that does not require Microsoft Office, such as a console application or Windows Forms project, add a reference to the
   `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.dll` and
   `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll assemblies`.
2. Add the following Imports or using statements to the top of your code file.

   `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications;
   using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime;`
3. Call the static AddCustomization method.

The following code example uses the AddCustomization overload. This overload takes the full path of the document and a Uri that specifies the location of the deployment manifest for the customization you want to attach to the document. This example assumes that a Word document named WordDocument1.docx is on the desktop, and that the deployment manifest is located in a folder that is named Publish that is also on the desktop.

```
string documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\WordDocument1.docx";
int runtimeVersion = 0;

try
{
    runtimeVersion = ServerDocument.GetCustomizationVersion(documentPath);

    // Make sure that this document does not yet have any Visual Studio Tools 
    // for Office customizations.
    if (runtimeVersion == 0)
    {
        string deployManifestPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Publish\WordDocument1.vsto";

        Uri deploymentManifestUri = new Uri(deployManifestPath);
        ServerDocument.AddCustomization(documentPath, deploymentManifestUri);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The document was successfully customized.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The document is already customized.");
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The specified document does not exist.");
}
catch (DocumentNotCustomizedException ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The document could not be customized.\n" +
        ex.Message);
}
```

4. Build the project and run the application on the computer where you want to attach the customization. The computer must have the Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set LoadBehaviour to `0x10` => `Load first time, then load on demand`? This should make Office load your addin the first time you execute it and internally cache it. It will then change the value to `0x9`... The subsequent times, the app will load on demand.

Comment: When I changed to 0x10 the splash screen said the AddIn was being loaded (did not do that previously) but the 'Could not create an instance of startup object...' error was still thrown once the document loaded.

For what it's worth, I have no reference to the GUID that is being embedded in the VSTO path in the Word document anywhere in the new AddIn. I'm assuming that Word would somehow know to only load the AddIn if that GUID is included?

Comment: What is it set to, after you get the error? And when you set it to `3` it still works?

Comment: It stays at 0x10 and if I set it to 3 it loads for all documents.